# script in Javascript or Jquery for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started it in javascript but if someone have better in Jquery i'll take it.
I explain the context: i have a few questions and each ones has answers, i would like to click on a question and then the answers appear. I already did this:

```
document.querySelector(".question").onclick = function() {
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.item_group_resultat')).display=='none'){
document.querySelector(".item_group_resultat").style.display="block";
} 
else {
document.querySelector(".item_group_resultat").style.display="none";
}
}
```

the problem is that the only one works but not others.

here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
        <h1 class="titre"></h1>
        <div class="navigation" id="style-7">
            <ul class="item_group">
                <li class="item titre"></li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="resultat">
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat"></li>
              <li class="item content_resultat"></li>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat"></li>
                <li class="item content_resultat"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat"></li>
                <li class="item content_resultat"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat"></li>
                <li class="item content_resultat"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat"></li>
                <li class="item content_resultat"></li>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well `document.querySelector` is going to find the first element that matches, it has no clue it supposed to match another one. You need to code it so it finds the related element. Since you did not share HTML code, it is hard to give an answer.

Comment: `querySelector` only ever returns a maximum of _one_ element. You need `querySelectorAll`, if you want to select _multiple_ elements based on a class. And you will need to _loop over_ the resulting set, and attach your click handler to each one individually. Yes, jQuery makes this a lot easier - but if you want to go that route, then you need to go read up on it yourself a bit first. And if you still have problems, then give us a proper [mre], before any further discussion of the issue.

Comment: Please share your simple HTML code to know how questions & answers are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the update vanilla JS solution:

```html
<div class="content">
        <h1 class="titre"></h1>
        <div class="navigation" id="style-7">
            <ul class="item_group">
                <li class="item titre">Q</li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#">4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="question" href="#">5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="resultat">
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat">1</li>
              <li class="item content_resultat">1</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat">2</li>
                <li class="item content_resultat">2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat">3</li>
                <li class="item content_resultat">3</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat">4</li>
                <li class="item content_resultat">4</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item_group item_group_resultat">
                <li class="item titre_resultat">5</li>
                <li class="item content_resultat">5</li>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.question {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.item_group_resultat {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector(".navigation").addEventListener("click", function(e){

   let currentIdx;
   Array.from(this.querySelectorAll(".question")).some( (q,idx) => ( q === e.target ) ? ( currentIdx = idx, true ) : false );
   let prev = document.querySelector(".item_group_resultat.active");
   document.querySelectorAll(".item_group_resultat")[currentIdx].classList.toggle("active");
   prev && prev.classList.remove("active");

});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/gOpmzPW)

Comment: Hi 'im back i would like to get another help, i would like to script a scroll to. When i click on a question it will scroll to the active result, could you help me ?

Comment: These two links might be a good start (JS/jQuery):

https://usefulangle.com/post/156/javascript-scroll-to-element
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this:

```
$('.question').click(function() {
   var index = $(this).parent().index();
   $('.item_group_resultat').eq(index).toggle().siblings().hide();
});
```

- `$(this).parent().index()` will get the index of clicked `.question`
- and the `toggle()` will toggle between hide and show for the `item_group_resultat` present in the same index but inside different div.

Comment: thanks a lot that work well. Do you know how to when i click in a other question the previous answer disappear ?